# How Can I Use typeahead in Input Filed to get the Values in Angularjs?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, meanjs

I am using MEAN stack in my application with AngularJS as my front-end. How can i use typeahead in input filed to get the values in angularjs , actually we get the value if we using select option, but we expecting for type-ahead option ...please look into plunker for the reference [My Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IbNWmpGMPyNFJJAPbUXX?p=preview).

- In plunker first select option used to get the without array values.
- Second select option are used to get the value in array of `user`. so we used like `ng-options="item.user.displayName for item in questions"`
- But we expecting for typeahead option to get the `displayNmae` values in array of `user`. so we used like `typeahead="item as item.user.displayName for item in questions | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8"` But we could't get the answer...
- what we exactly looking in third input filed if we type a name the drop down should need to display...
- Please if any one knows the solution ,please update plunker as well to know the solution.

**My Data:-**

```
$scope.questions = [
{
"_id": "583433ddc021a5d02949a51b",
"user": {
"_id": "5834336ac021a5d02949a51a",
"displayName": "mani R",
"location": "ICF",
"dob": "1991-10-05T18:30:00.000Z",
"religion": "Christian",
"roles": [
"user"
],
"profileImageURL": "modules/users/client/img/profile/default.png"
},
"__v": 0,
"upvoters": [],
"category": "Moral Ethics",
"content": "Dhoni",
"title": "which batsman is best in the world?",
"created": "2016-11-22T12:02:37.376Z"
},
{
"_id": "582c34b3ff26bd603e1e5383",
"user": {
"_id": "58072aba0f82a61823c434df",
"displayName": "Table 1",
"dob": "1991-10-04T18:30:00.000Z",
"location": "Icf",
"religion": "Hindu",
"roles": [
"admin"
],
"profileImageURL": "./modules/users/client/img/profile/uploads/c756711556ab6864f408697c7a98aedc"
},
"__v": 1,
"upvoters": [],
"users": [],
"comments": [
{
"created": 1479365394684,
"email": "ms@e21designs.com",
"name": "Table 1",
"commentText": "Dhoni"
}
],
"friend_tag": [],
"emotion": "Confused",
"category": "Environment & Health",
"content": "sachin?",
"title": "who is best player in this world?",
"created": "2016-11-16T10:28:03.859Z"
},
{
"_id": "582c3418ff26bd603e1e5382",
"user": {
"_id": "582c1f4b53cf7fec2ddf282e",
"displayName": "selvam R",
"dob": "1991-10-04T18:30:00.000Z",
"roles": [
"kp"
],
"profileImageURL": "modules/users/client/img/profile/default.png"
},
"__v": 0,
"upvoters": [],
"category": "Environment & Health",
"content": "he is tennis player",
"created": "2016-11-16T10:25:28.835Z"
},
{
"_id": "582ad554714543e037cf3bf2",
"user": {
"_id": "58072aba0f82a61823c434df",
"displayName": "Table 1",
"dob": "1991-10-04T18:30:00.000Z",
"location": "Icf",
"religion": "Hindu",
"roles": [
"admin"
],
"profileImageURL": "./modules/users/client/img/profile/uploads/c756711556ab6864f408697c7a98aedc"
},
"__v": 1,
"upvoters": [
"ms@e21designs.com"
],
"upvotes": 1,
"category": "Moral Ethics",
"created": "2016-11-15T09:28:52.403Z"
},
{
"_id": "5821e7c667b70aac2b8fdfdc",
"user": {
"_id": "58072aba0f82a61823c434df",
"displayName": "Table 1",
"dob": "1991-10-04T18:30:00.000Z",
"location": "Icf",
"religion": "Hindu",
"roles": [
"admin"
],
"profileImageURL": "./modules/users/client/img/profile/uploads/c756711556ab6864f408697c7a98aedc"
},
"__v": 1,
"upvoters": [
"ms@e21designs.com"
],
"upvotes": 1,
"category": "Religion & Culture",
"created": "2016-11-08T14:57:10.354Z"
}
]
```

**My Html:-**

```
<div style="margin-top: 20px;">
  <label style="color: green;">3. Typeahead Not Working</label>
    <input ng-model="friend" typeahead-min-length="3" typeahead="item as item.user.displayName for item in questions | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8">

 </div>
```

- We got the answer with the help of Mr.J-Mean, but We have one more problem , if we type the name like `table 1` in Typeahead input, it's showing like three `Table 1` names ,  if we have  same names are in our data means we expecting  to show only one name like `Table 1` please help us...please update your answer in plunker as well to know the solution....thanks

Comment: what typeahead plugin are you using?

Comment: thanks for your comment we are not used typeahead plugin on here, please look into my plunker for reference...thanks....

Comment: Then how is the typeahead going to work?

Comment: If you know the solution Please give some suggestion and how to use...thanks..

Comment: This is what i would recommend: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead

Comment: Thank you so much for your help it's really useful to us... thanks....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this working it will required plugin- I have used Typeahead of [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Please find solution to your problem

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('TypeaheadDemo', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngTagsInput']);

    app.controller('TypeaheadCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $filter) {

        var _selected;
        $scope.questions = [
      {
          "_id": "583433ddc021a5d02949a51b",
          "user": {
              "_id": "5834336ac021a5d02949a51a",
              "displayName": "mani R",
              "location": "ICF",
              "dob": "1991-10-05T18:30:00.000Z",
              "religion": "Christian",
              "roles": [
              "user"
              ],
              "profileImageURL": "modules/users/client/img/profile/default.png"
          },
          "__v": 0,
          "upvoters": [],
          "category": "Moral Ethics",
          "content": "Dhoni",
          "title": "which batsman is best in the world?",
          "created": "2016-11-22T12:02:37.376Z"
      },
      {
          "_id": "582c34b3ff26bd603e1e5383",
          "user": {
              "_id": "58072aba0f82a61823c434df",
              "displayName": "Table 1",
              "dob": "1991-10-04T18:30:00.000Z",
              "location": "Icf",
              "religion": "Hindu",
              "roles": [
              "admin"
              ],
              "profileImageURL": "./modules/users/client/img/profile/uploads/c756711556ab6864f408697c7a98aedc"
          },
          "__v": 1,
          "upvoters": [],
          "users": [],
          "comments": [
          {
              "created": 1479365394684,
              "email": "ms@e21designs.com",
              "name": "Table 1",
              "commentText": "Dhoni"
          }
          ],
          "friend_tag": [],
          "emotion": "Confused",
          "category": "Environment & Health",
          "content": "sachin?",
          "title": "who is best player in this world?",
          "created": "2016-11-16T10:28:03.859Z"
      },
      {
          "_id": "582c3418ff26bd603e1e5382",
          "user": {
              "_id": "582c1f4b53cf7fec2ddf282e",
              "displayName": "selvam R",
              "dob": "1991-10-04T18:30:00.000Z",
              "roles": [
              "kp"
              ],
              "profileImageURL": "modules/users/client/img/profile/default.png"
          },
          "__v": 0,
          "upvoters": [],
          "category": "Environment & Health",
          "content": "he is tennis player",
          "created": "2016-11-16T10:25:28.835Z"
      },
      {
          "_id": "582ad554714543e037cf3bf2",
          "user": {
              "_id": "58072aba0f82a61823c434df",
              "displayName": "Table 1",
              "dob": "1991-10-04T18:30:00.000Z",
              "location": "Icf",
              "religion": "Hindu",
              "roles": [
              "admin"
              ],
              "profileImageURL": "./modules/users/client/img/profile/uploads/c756711556ab6864f408697c7a98aedc"
          },
          "__v": 1,
          "upvoters": [
          "ms@e21designs.com"
          ],
          "upvotes": 1,
          "category": "Moral Ethics",
          "created": "2016-11-15T09:28:52.403Z"
      },
      {
          "_id": "5821e7c667b70aac2b8fdfdc",
          "user": {
              "_id": "58072aba0f82a61823c434df",
              "displayName": "Table 1",
              "dob": "1991-10-04T18:30:00.000Z",
              "location": "Icf",
              "religion": "Hindu",
              "roles": [
              "admin"
              ],
              "profileImageURL": "./modules/users/client/img/profile/uploads/c756711556ab6864f408697c7a98aedc"
          },
          "__v": 1,
          "upvoters": [
          "ms@e21designs.com"
          ],
          "upvotes": 1,
          "category": "Religion & Culture",
          "created": "2016-11-08T14:57:10.354Z"
      }
        ]

        $scope.filterTags = function ($query) {
            var filterList = $filter('filter')($scope.questions, $query);         //filter the data  
            var removedDuplicate = $filter('unique')(filterList, 'user.displayName');//Removed duplicates
            return angular.forEach(removedDuplicate, function (question) {
                question.custName = question.user.displayName;
            });

            return removedDuplicate;
        };
    });

    app.filter('unique', function () {

        return function (items, filterOn) {

            if (filterOn === false) {
                return items;
            }

            if ((filterOn || angular.isUndefined(filterOn)) && angular.isArray(items)) {
                var hashCheck = {}, newItems = [];

                var extractValueToCompare = function (item) {
                    if (angular.isObject(item) && angular.isString(filterOn)) {
                        return item[filterOn];
                    } else {
                        return item;
                    }
                };

                angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
                    var valueToCheck, isDuplicate = false;

                    for (var i = 0; i < newItems.length; i++) {
                        if (angular.equals(extractValueToCompare(newItems[i]), extractValueToCompare(item))) {
                            isDuplicate = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!isDuplicate) {
                        newItems.push(item);
                    }

                });
                items = newItems;
            }
            return items;
        };
    });
})();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html >
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>

    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.2.0.js"></script>

    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-tags-input/3.1.1/ng-tags-input.bootstrap.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-tags-input/3.1.1/ng-tags-input.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-tags-input/3.1.1/ng-tags-input.js"></script>
    
</head>
<body ng-app="TypeaheadDemo">
    <div class='container-fluid typeahead-demo' ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">

        <div>
            <label>1. Without array value</label>
            <select ng-model="class" ng-options="item.category for item in questions"></select>
        </div>

        <div style="margin-top: 11px;">
            <label>2. With array value</label>
            <select style="margin-left: 20px;" ng-model="class" ng-options="item.user.displayName for item in questions"></select>
        </div>

        <div style="margin-top: 20px;">
            <label style="color: green;">3. Typeahead is Working Now:</label>
            <input ng-model="friend" typeahead-min-length="3" uib-typeahead="item as item.user.displayName for item in questions | filter : $viewValue | unique:'user.displayName'">
        </div>

        <div class="searchinput autosearchinput">
            <tags-input display-property="custName" add-on-enter="true" add-on-blur="true" add-from-autocomplete-only="true" placeholder="tag friends" ng-model="friends" title="tag friends">
                <auto-complete min-length='1' source="filterTags($query)"></auto-complete>
            </tags-input>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We have one more problem , if we type the name like `table 1` in Typeahead input it's showing like three `Table 1` names ,  if we have  same names are in our data means we exepecting  to show only one `Table 1` please help us...please update your answer in plunker as well to know the solution....thanks

Comment: Have updated solution to avoid duplicate table 1. Add new directive unique which will filter out repeated names.
Helpful link https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui-OLDREPO/blob/master/modules/filters/unique/unique.js 
I am also big fan of cricket man :)

Comment: hey thank you so much your are really genius in this field.... but i'm struggling lot sir... please keep touch with me and teach me lot...really nice to know you...ms@e21designs.com mail me when you are feel free...thanks your answer is useful to us ... thanks....

Comment: then sorry to disturbing you, actually why we used this Typeahead input means, actually we expecting to do like facebook tagging friends concept, so on here now we can able to tag one friend ,so how we can tag `multiple friends` on this `Typeahead field` ?...sorry to disturbing so if you know the solution please help us...we tired to use `ng-list` but it's not working.... please help us.. if you update the plunker it's very easy to understand?... thanks..

Comment: This link will help you to resolve your issue http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/. Bit busy to won't be able to update my solution

Comment: thanks , i already knew this link then i was installed `npm install ng-tags-input` in my terminal then it's not working to us, that's why we asked help to you ...so when you feel free update the solution asap....thanks

Comment: @ J-Mean hi sir thank you for your update...can you explain this how you did the `ng-tags-input`....if you have time please update my plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/IbNWmpGMPyNFJJAPbUXX?p=preview to know the exact answer thank you soo much for your help.....